# Android-How to make moving onscreen objects extend Button

Tags: java, android, button, extends

In an app Im working on I have a class that extends a surface view and another that handles all calculations to figure out where and when objects should be drawn onscreen. Right now I have a sort of hacky way of registering screen clicks where a list of objects is parsed through on each click and the closest object takes the click. This works when there is only 3 or 4 objects onscreen but when I have more the clicks register for the wrong objects.

What Im trying to do is to make the onscreen objects extend the button class so I can just pass a MotionEvent to them when they are clicked. But because of the way that the classes I have are set up its a bit confusing to me at the moment on how this could be done.

Does anybody possible know of any tutorials that deal with extending the button class to use with moving onscreen objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to determine which object drawn to the screen has been clicked?

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for but when I've implemented a custom view the past, I've typically handled click detection like this:

I get the x and y coordinates of the objects that you want to be clickable. In your onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) method within your SurfaceView class, have some if statement that checks whether the x and y of the click is within the bounds of your object.

Here's some code to better illustrate what I'm saying:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    // If the user touches the space occupied by object1
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
            && event.getX() <= object1.xPosition + object1.width 
            && event.getX() >= object1.xPosition
            && event.getY() >= object1.yPosition 
            && event.getY() < object1.yPosition + object1.height)
    {
            // The click was in the bounds of object1's current location
        object1.doSomething();
    }
    // ......
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense and is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Yes it makes complete sense :) my problem is that most everything has been so abstracted to the point that I have to back track through the inheritance chain to figure out where and when to register motion event. I was handed this project when the last person working on it ran into the same problem. Im using a canvas to capture the drawing and then display the canvas on the surfaceView. Im guessing my next step is to figure out how to pass the x,y of the objects from the canvas in the surface view to my onTouchEvent

Answer (score 1):

I think you kind of mixing stuff. Button is usually used in layout (the xml layout stuff). When you use surface view you (most likely) need to implement your own "button".
However, it is probably possible to just overlay a frameview on top of your surface view and place the button on that view.

Comment: Well what Im trying to do is take objects that I already have implemented which are freely moving about on the screen and make their class extend Button so I can make them clickable onscreen objects. The objects are represented onscreen by bitmaps and what Id like is for when a user clicks one it just opens without using the hacky way I have implemented at the moment which has to traverse through 3 classes and isnt very accurate with high numbers of onscreen objects.